# Docker pull or Docker run doesn't actually do anything

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run something called Traildash via it's docker container on a VM via chef (once I get it running I'll move it to an AWS instance). So I've installed docker onto the VM and so I tell chef to run

```
docker run -i -d -p 80:80 \
appliedtrust/traildash
```

or even

```
docker pull appliedtrust/traildash
```

on the VM and all it does is:

```
Unable to find image 'appliedtrust/traildash' locally
Pulling repository appliedtrust/traildash
2015/03/16 12:40:38 Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/appliedtrust/traildash/images: x509: certificate is valid for ssl7302.cloudflare.com, *.archeagemall.co
m, *.astrubbank.com, *.billhr2847.com, *.dallasjuniorforum.org, *.goudportal.nl, *.habbinfo.info, *.hoistandcrane.com, *.jlfresno.org, *.jlknoxville.org, *.jlsantabarbara.org, *.jl
wichita.org, *.jrleagueabilene.com, *.okaygoods.com, *.pbajf.org, *.stansberryonline.com, *.unfairmovie.com, *.usepnd.com, *.vaccineinjuryhelpcenter.com, archeagemall.com, astrubba
nk.com, billhr2847.com, dallasjuniorforum.org, goudportal.nl, habbinfo.info, hoistandcrane.com, jlfresno.org, jlknoxville.org, jlsantabarbara.org, jlwichita.org, jrleagueabilene.co
m, okaygoods.com, pbajf.org, stansberryonline.com, unfairmovie.com, usepnd.com, vaccineinjuryhelpcenter.com, not index.docker.io
```

and then nothing, the container won't actually start nor do I see any files pulled unless docker pulls the files into a different directory?

What do I do to get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing everything right. But if you running it outside of EC2 (with IAM Role setted up), you have to explicitly pass AWS creds and optionally other parameters. For more information take a look at https://github.com/AppliedTrust/traildash#quickstart

Comment: In the end, I've decided to ditch docker and just use it directly but I will tick this as being correct.